# SQL - How to specify results

Tags: sql

I have an assignment that wants me to find schools in an area that have an enrollment greater than 500. I've input this: `"zipcode" = '10002' OR "zipcode" = '10003' AND "enrolled" > 500`. But with this, instead of results being over 500, I also get results less than 500. I've also tried AND NO < 499 and that hasn't worked as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You immediate problem is that you need parentheses.  However, you should learn to use `IN`, because that also fixes the problem:

```
where "zipcode" in ('10002', '10003') and "enrolled" > 500
```

Without parentheses, your version is interpreted as:

```
where "zipcode" = '10002' or
      ("zipcode" =  '10003' and "enrolled" > 500)
```

The condition on `enrolled` only applies to zip code 10003.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon Linoff. Everything is now working as it should!